# Ionic/Angular testing: this.storage.ready is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I am trying to mock Ionic's Storage provider for my Angular unit tests but I'm getting stuck.  Here's my mock:

```
export class StorageMock {
  driver: string;
  vals: {};

  constructor() {
    // super({})
  }

  clear() {
    return new Promise<void>((res) => res())
  }

  ready() {
    return new Promise<LocalForage>((res) => res())
  }

  get(key: string) {
    return new Promise((res) => res(this.vals[key]))
  }

  set(key, val) {
    return new Promise((res) => {
      this.vals[key] = val;
      res()
    })
  }

  remove(key) {
    return new Promise((res) => {
      delete this.vals[key];
      res()
    })
  }
}
```

And my test is setup this way:

```
describe('ReEvaluationComponent', () => {
  let component: ReEvaluationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReEvaluationComponent>;
  let mockGlobalsService = jasmine.createSpyObj('GlobalsService', ['base_url'])
  let checkInsService: any;
  let injector: TestBed;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ReEvaluationComponent ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        CheckInsProvider,
        WeighInsProvider,
        PurchasesService,
        TransactionsProvider,
        {provide: Storage, useValue: StorageMock},
        {provide: GlobalsService, useValue: mockGlobalsService}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReEvaluationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  ...
```

I thought the line: `{provide: Storage, useValue: StorageMock}` would fix the issue but I'm still getting the error:

```
Failed: this.storage.ready is not a function
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

They replace `ready()` with `create()`.

Reference:

- https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-ionic-storage-v3/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are importing correspondingly `Storage` and declaring it in the constructor. So, after check it you can use like this:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

constructor(private storage: Storage) {
}

this.storage.ready();
```